# How to have Gradle do a custom compile for a specific test directory before running tests?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using kotlinpoet to auto-generate some factory files.  In the test suite itself I need to generate the factories based on some test parameters, and then compile the source files and class load them so I can create an instance for further testing.

I have messed around with doing it via Gradle, but I am running into issues with circular dependencies when I try to this (for good reason):

```
// Custom task to pre-generate factories needed for tests
task generateFactories(type: JavaExec) {
    mainClass = "com.factories.GenerateTestFactories"
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    doLast {
        println "Factory generation completed"
    }
}

compileTestKotlin.dependsOn(generateFactories)

test.dependsOn generateFactories
```

So I would effectively need it to do a second pass on just a specific directory under the test root so that my tests can class load the newly compiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to create a new source set called `codegen` that has access to the configuration files in the `test` source, as well as the code in the `main` source.  I then set it up to run a job to do the code generation, and set the test compile gradle task to depend on it completing.

Answer (score 1):

When you are executing a test, you are inside a Gradle task which is itself executing code in a separate environment. Trying to start a Gradle task from there is not going to go well, as you concluded. For a start, you'd need a whole new Gradle invocation.

Alternatively you could generate the source files, recompile and classload the new classes, all within your test and without Gradle's help. If you have a lot of cases to test then maybe you need to do that, but it sounds like hard work.

I suggest that a more feasible way would be to:

- Decide on the parameters determining a small number of KotlinPoet generations in advance, or have it that the user can provide them to Gradle ahead of running the tests (perhaps from the command line or in a config file)
- Generate those Kotlin files in one or a number of new Gradle tasks (using a number of tasks if you want to isolate new code generations from each other in separate ultimate compilations)
- If the whole test suite needs all of these, add their outputs into test compilation so the tests will depend on and pick up the new code
- Or, it might be more appropriate to break up your tests into several tasks and have each test compilation depend on the one or ones it needs